# Some Fontawesome icons not displaying in Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, font-awesome

I've noticed a problem when using Fontawesome with Safari (on Mac OS X Mavericks). Some icons, such as Twitter, Instagram etc. do not appear. At first I assumed they were removed because of a copyright issue, but they work fine in Chrome. Here's a screenshot of Safari vs Chrome, and the missing icons in Safari. The web inspector doesn't display any errors. It works displays fine in MobileSafari too.

[image: Screenshot]

<strike>Does anyone know the reason why only a few icons wouldn't show up? Is there a fix for this?</strike>
Thanks!

**EDIT** Turns out the AdBlock extension for Safari was causing this issue, its back to normal when AdBlock is disabled.

Comment: It's working for me.  Is your Safari up to date?  Is this happening 100% of the time?

Comment: I'm running 7.0.2 which I believe is the latest one.
Actually I've figured out why it does this. It turns out that the AdBlock extension was causing the issues.
Thanks for you help!

Comment: You should answer your own question and resolve it then.  No need to answer your question in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the AdBlock extension for Safari was causing this issue, its back to normal when AdBlock is disabled.

Comment: any idea what AdBlock was doing to cause this?